# Testing file set

Tags: java, android, testing

I'm writing a file browser for android and I just had to fix a bug because of a white space parsing error. That got me thinking, I bet someone out there has created a set of file, corrupt, odd characters, long long names, the works, that would be easy to use in testing (and come up with cases I didn't think of)

I'm not having much luck finding one however. Does anyone know where such a set of test files may be?

Thank you

edit: File types: pdf, jpg, html. Though wildcards welcome too, but jpgs would be primary.

Comment: Could you clarify more what you are wanting? Thanks. I am assuming you want a set of "bad" files to make a program that finds the errors in the "bad" files?

Comment: Yes sorry, I updated my question accordingly. Bad, odd names, I rather root them out now than let my coworkers find them :)

Comment: I have such file sets, and I suppose several other testers do as well, the problem is that they are created at work and therefore they are the intellectual property of the employer and not really suitable to share online.

It is not a bad idea though, it would be useful to create such an archive and open source it, at the moment I will put it on my to-do list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I  needed a large amount of files for testing, and I came across
https://code.google.com/p/imagetestsuite/
It took a lot of searching to find so I thought I'd come back and share it with the future person in need.